# Display for on target Monitor

Tags: c#, winforms

Not sure what i'm missing here. Trying to display forms on certain monitors but they all end up on the same monitor.

```
private static List<Form> forms = new List<Form>();

public static void Run()
{
    foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        Image gfx = GetDesktop(screen);
        forms.Add(CreateForm(gfx, screen));
    }

    forms.ForEach(f => f.Show());
}

private static Form CreateForm(Image desktop, Screen screen)
{
    Form frm = new Form();
    frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    frm.BackgroundImage = desktop;
    frm.Location = screen.WorkingArea.Location;
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm.TopMost = true;
    frm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    return frm;
}
```

Comment: Is `screens` a `List<Form>`? If so, wouldn't it be less confusing to call it `forms`?

Comment: eh either way lol, updated code to reflect so it's easier to understand.

Comment: @kol that did the tick :) Create that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;`